# WEBRTC with flutter

Tags: database, flutter, webrtc, flutter-dependencies, webrtc-android

Will it be possible to use WEBRTC In `flutter`?

The application will be a cross platform application using flutter,

The application will connect 100 people at a time in video and audio calling,

So can I use WEBRTC in flutter,

If not then what I can use to perform Video and audio call In flutter?

Comment: search in pub.dev, for example: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc

Comment: You can also use something like https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet